# how to recive data whitout port forwarding using udp

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, port

First of, I'm an complete noob in socket programing, so plz tell me if you thing that i'm doing something wrong.

So, I have been trying to program an udp server for an simple fps game.

On local networks everything is working fine, if i however try to use my code on the Internet i do get some problems. my server can receive data from the clients whiteout problems and can send data to the clients, if the port that it is sending on is open on the client, if it isn't the client won't receive any data. (the ports on the server is all open). my question is now, Is there any way to receive data over the Internet without the need of opening/forwarding an port?

*(the client() function is constantly repeated in an loop)*

my code for receiving data is as follow:

```
import socket

server_IP = 'ip of server'
Client_port = 3560
Server_port = 5000
Client_socket = None
First_run = True
first = True

def client():
    global server_IP
    global Client_port
    global Server_port
    global Client_socket
    global first
    if first == True:
        try:
            local = ('', Client_port)
            host = (server_IP, Server_port)
            Client_socket  = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            Client_socket.bind(local)
            Client_socket.setblocking(False)
            first = False
        except:
            print("Failed")
    try:
        data, connection = Client_socket.recvfrom(512)
    except socket.error:
        return
    if data:
        #irrelevant code handling the data...
```

and the server send code is is locking like this:

```
import socket
server_socket = None
server_port = 5000
Data_Port = 3560
print("importing the socket...")
try:
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error as msg:
    server_socket = None
try:
    server_socket.bind(("", server_port))
except socket.error as msg:
    server_socket.close()
    server_socket = None
if server_socket is None:
    print('could not open socket')
    ret = False
server_socket.sendto(Data_to_Send, ('client ip here',Data_Port))
```

ofc this is only parts of the code, but I suppose that it is the relevant ones.
If there is no way of receiving data without the need of open/forward ports in the way that i'm sending/receiving the data, plz suggest an way that can do this, if there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at UDP hole punching:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

The basic premise is that the client connects to your server first creating an entry in the NAT routing table. The server then looks at the request to see which port the NAT router used to send the request. You should be able to send a UDP packet to this port, which should then be forwarded to the client in the private network.

So in summary, don't hardcode your port to `3560`. You need to change this port based on where the UDP packet came from.

You may also want to consider using TCP which is a connection based protocol (UDP is connectionless)- when a connection is established from the client to the server, it's very easy to send data back and forth over this connection.

Comment: okay, this gave me some more understanding, I do not however understand how the client is suppose to know what port it should bind to (or maby it don't need to bind?). I'm using the socket.sendto method to send data to the server, this method is using an random? port every time, I can easy make the server respond to this random port (respond on the same port as it received the data on), but how can I make the client look for the answer on this port?, as it is random every time do I need to rebind it on every call? and how do i, on the client get the port used on the last sendto call?

Answer (score 0):

as this question where hard to find an clear answer to and as i got it to work, thanks to the explanation given by Martin Konecny on hole punching (eg. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching), but also thanks to my own many "try-and-error" attempts.

what i where doing wrong where most likely the fact that I where closing the socket on the client that where used to make the sendto call and then trying to listen for an answer from the server on an new socket. this do Not work, or at least I diden't get it to work. If i however did not close the socket, and listened for an answer on the same socket that I used to make the sendto call, everything worked fine. It turned out that I diden't even need to bind the socket as i'm doing in the question for this to work.